# Application launches only on PCs with Visual Studio installed. What could be the reason of such behavior?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

Does Visual Studio installs some dll's that are missing otherwise?

Comment: Visual C++ runtime libraries are probably the most common; make sure you install the correct version required by your project. If that doesn't help, look at the dependencies in your project.

Comment: Are you just copying .exe files from system to system? That is incorrect way of deploying software on any case.

Comment: You need to use [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and add respective dll-s to your installation process.

Comment: I am installing application by the installer that I made. It used to work for years. I've added couple of Third Party libraries and suddenly encountered this problem.

Comment: Generated code in VS may depend on certain VS specific DLLs. For deployment, you may need to include the appropriate redistributable. Please, have at look at this: [The latest supported Visual C++ downloads](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found out what was wrong: new Third Party lib  that I added was linked to vcruntime140D.dll and ucrtbased.dll

This is what caused the problem